# Rotate a steering wheel - WPF

Tags: wpf, rotation

I have a WPF image. I will render a steering wheel in it. I would like to simulate the steering wheel rotation. User shall touch anywhere in steering wheel. It should rotate clockwise and anti clockwise. The range is 0 to 400 degree and 0 to -400 degree. It is exactly same as in normal car.

Any ideas to start? Kindly give a logical example, I am a developer, but not a mathematician so I don't know how to calculate the angle of rotation.

My target device is a touch based windows tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Animation in WPF is easy... there's no need for any of us to be mathematicians. You can rotate any `UIElement` very easily using the [`RotateTransform` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`UIElement.RenderTransform` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Ellipse StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="50">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform />
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

Now to animate that `RotateTransform`, we can use the [`Storyboard` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) (which has to go inside a `BeginStoryboard` element:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).
(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2" />
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Finally, we can trigger this animation to start when the control is loaded:

```
<Ellipse StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="50" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="
                        (Ellipse.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform />
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

With these examples, I trust that you will follow the links to find out how to complete your requirements, rather than asking me to do *all* of your work.

Comment: I understand WPF is having strong support for RotateRenderTransform. But in my case, it is not easy, I think. It is not starting a double animation in a button click or image loading. But when I touch and hold the steering wheel image, it has to rotate clockwise and anti clockwise accordingly. It will not be a continuous rotation too.   On each mouse move OR touch move, it has to find the new angle of rotation. The example is great and I think I have to CODE it and supply the angle externally. For finding the angle, I may need some maths.

Comment: My friend, I have provided you with links to the relevant pages on MSDN and a working example to get you started. If you read through the linked pages, you will see that you can also start animations from code. As these are *your* requirements, *you* have to do some work to fulfil them. I'm really not sure what more that I can do without doing all of *your* work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx

and this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx